# links to answers cause page reload

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

The "link" link in the answers are not relative anchor links ('#') but send the user to a completely new URL.

In a question with URL...

> http://site.example.com/questions/1276/title

Answers are linked like this:

> http://site.example.com/questions/1276/title/1234#1234

Many times, some answers reference other answers. With the current linking scheme, this reloads the page. With the proposed scheme below, It would just scroll to the linked answer and not reload the page.

> http://site.example.com/questions/1276/title#1234

Comment: we originally had hash only but ran into severe issues (which will be evident as reported below) and now have the current scheme you see..

Answer (score 3):

You *can* actually just copy the hash portion of the URL and use that in your links ([view source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6584821c-7353-4f33-997a-9c8da10b3f92/view-source) for example). Then it won't reload.

It'll also *fail to work* if there are numerous answers and the one you're linking to is on a different page from your own...

Answer (score 3):

Some questions have more than one page of answers, and so a relative anchor link doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

It's also required (at the moment) to highlight the linked answer.

Comment: highlighting only works for registered and logged in users, too.