# Accept magic links wherever a URL is accepted

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, magic-links

Currently, one can [make short links to some common SE-related locations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) with the [magic-links](/questions/tagged/magic-links) syntax:

```
[magic-keyword]
```

Essentially, it fills the same niche as [Interwiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki) in MediaWiki.

But, the feature is not as complete as its MediaWiki counterpart. Sometimes, I wish to insert such a link but provide my own text that more organically fits into the message. Current syntax doesn't allow me to do that.

---

So, I propose to:

- Support and accept the "inter-SE" links wherever a URL is accepted:

  - in Markdown

    - primarily as a syntax like `[text](magic-keyword)`
    - (discussable) I didn't yet need the support in `[text][ref#]` syntax but it may be easier to support both at the same time
  - (discussable) in Hyperlink wizard

    - possibly, auto-convert eligible full URLs to these in line with [Allow and/or automatically construct relative and anchor links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280538/allow-and-or-automatically-construct-relative-and-achor-links/280539#280539)
- (discussable) To avoid confusion with pristine URLs if/where it arises, we can change the syntax a little: to, say, `[magic-prefix:<optional-rest-of-the-URL>]` like, you guessed it, MediaWiki already does.

Comment: So, use `magic-prefix` as the URL scheme? Seems reasonable.